# How to change background color of toolbar button in javascript which is added in firefox using xul

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, xul

I have added toolbar button in firefox using xul and now i want to change background color of that toolbar button in javascript. Anybody please help

My xul button code is:

```
<toolbox id="navigator-toolbox">
    <toolbar id="TutTB-Toolbar" toolbarname="Tutorial Toolbar" accesskey="T"
       class="chromeclass-toolbar" context="toolbar-context-menu" 
       hidden="false" persist="hidden">
       <toolbaritem flex="0">
          <toolbarbutton id="TutTB-Web-Button" tooltiptext="Search"
             label="button" oncommand="alert('ok');" />
       </toolbaritem>
       <toolbarspring />
    </toolbar>
</toolbox>
```

And i try to access it in javascript through following line of code

```
var p = document.getElementById("TutTB-Web-Button");
alert(p.textContent);
document.getElementById("TutTB-Web-Button").style.backgroundColor='red';
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely that has to do with the default appearance of the xul elements. You have to do `-moz-appearance:none`

Try like this:

In your CSS:

```
.myRedClass{
    -moz-appearance: none;
    background-color:red;
}
```

In your JS:

```
document.getElementById("TutTB-Web-Button").classList.add('myRedClass');
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: yes thanks alot it works and if i want to add listner to it @Filipe Silva what we have to do add listener in xul? there is any way to add onclick listner in javascript??

Comment: You can see [this part](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL_Event_Propagation#Adding_an_Event_Listener) of the documentation: `document.getElementById("TutTB-Web-Button").addEventListener("click", function() { alert('Hello'); }, true);`

Comment: thanks alot for help i will see the part of documentation. Thanks again

Comment: please there is one more query i want to make the toolbar button to blink on certain event but its not blinking my other button on webpage are blinking through this code but toolbar button is not blinking my code is:    blinker1();
                                         function blinker1(){
 document.getElementById("TutTB-Web-Button").classList.add('myRedClass');
 setTimeout("document.getElementById('TutTB-Web-Button').classList.add('myblueclass');", 500);
 setTimeout(blinker1,800);
 //alert("blink func");
}

Comment: To have the button blink looks like a horrible idea. Why would you want that?

Comment: @ Filipe Silva yes its horrible idea u are right :). can you tell me how to search webpage for certain string in javascript in firefo extension?? I have also asked another question

Comment: And please take a look m waiting :(

Comment: i have marked please try to answer my other question m stuck on that

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that. Have you tried searching for similar extensions that do that kind of find in page functionality?

Comment: i have searched for code in javascript, but not searched extension